# How to set callout response into my custom field vf pafe?

Tags: visualforce, controller, visualforce-component

vf page

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Opportunity" extensions="GetRestfulExample" action="{!fetchData}" contentType="text/plain">
     {!response}
</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class GetRestfulExample {
    private final String serviceEndpoint= 'https://th-apex-http-callout.herokuapp.com/animals?firstParam=Value1&secondParam=value2&thirdParam=Value3&forthParam=value4';
    public String Response { get; set;}
    public String Headers { get; set; }


    public GetRestfulExample(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
      this.opp = (Opportunity)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public Opportunity  opp;
    public void fetchData() {
     String oppId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
     Opportunity[] opps = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oppId];
     if (!opps.isEmpty()){
       opp = opps[0];}
        getAndParse(opp.product_name__c);

    }

  public void getAndParse(String objectId) {

    // Get the XML document from the external server
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(serviceEndpoint+ '0062800000G7unqAAB');

    req.setMethod('GET');
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);

    System.debug(res.getBody());
     this.Response =res.getBody();
  }
}
```

hi I am new to salesforce i want callout response should come to custom field can anyone help on this.my custom field is product name which is in opportunity(subject)